# How to add jQuery scroll event to a dynamically added div?

Tags: jquery

I am working on infinite scrolling for web page and the page rendering dynamically by a ajax call. I am unable to add scroll event to that html content. I have used following jQuery functions.

```
// .live() and .bind() are also not working in my case
$(document).on('scroll','#test' , function(){
/*
.
.
.
*/
});

html :-
<div style="overflow-y:auto">
.
.
.
.
.

</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you're using jQuery version 1.7 or later, what you have should work fine. Can you give a more complete example of both your HTML and JS.

Comment: and `$('#test').scroll(function(){})` is also not working?

Comment: what about this: `$( "body" ).delegate( "div", "scroll, function() { ... });` ?

Comment: @Vinc199789  sadly thats not working.

Answer (score 6):

The reason it doesn't work is because the "scroll" event doesn't bubble up like most other events (like "click" for example).

You can compare the [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) and the [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) and see that the "Bubbles" property is different.

This means that when your `#test` element scrolls, its parents are not notified, so your function in `$(document).on('scroll', '#test')` will not be called.

If I understand correctly, the `#test` element will be coming from an AJAX response and thus be added later to the document. If so, the easiest solution would be to add a "scroll" event listener to `#test` when you add it to the DOM.

So, let's suppose the following :

index.html

```
...
<div id="container">
    <!-- Will contain the HTML loaded by AJAX -->
</div>
...
```

ajax-data.html

```
...
<div>
    <div class="scrolling-element" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100px;">
       <p style="height:600px">Really tall paragraph that will make my parent scroll!</p>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Your jQuery AJAX call would look like :

```
$.ajax('ajax-data.html')
    .done(function( htmlData ) {
        var $newNode = $( htmlData );
        // Append to index.html
        $('#container').append( $newNode );
        // Add the scroll listener. Note that if multiple elements will have the same
        // behavior when scrolling, you may use a pre-defined function
        // (like scrollingFunction below) to have more performant code.
        $newNode.find('.scrolling-element').scroll( scrollingFunction );
    });

function scrollingFunction( event ) {
    console.log('scrolling');
}
```